# Angular.js service factory $http.get not calling my service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get data in service factory. Nothings happen.It executed code. But nothings happened. Dont know why?

[image]

Here is my service  code:

```js
'use strict';

app.factory('accountService', function($http, $location, $rootScope) {

  return {
    accounts: function() {
      $http.get('http://localhost:29045/AccountOperation.svc/GetAccounts').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
        var $promise = data;
        console.log(data);

      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my controller(calling factory from here):

```js
'use strict';
app.controller('accountController', function($scope, accountService, $rootScope) {
  $scope.accounts = function() {
    accountService.accounts();
  }
});
```

Also i didnt get error.

Comment: Do you ever call this function?

Comment: Show us how you call the accounts function please.

Comment: Does your application also run under the same port?

Comment: Yes running under same port

Comment: ok. your actual issue is unclear `Nothings happen.It executed code. But nothings happened`. What do you mean by that? Well you have not written anything to handle (or assign the response anywhere) and process the response from the ajax call so what do you expect will happen?

Answer (score 3):

On your account function you are not creating a promise or returning anything. Try:

```
app.factory('accountService', function($http, $location, $rootScope) {

  return {
    accounts: function() {
      return $http.get('http://localhost:29045/AccountOperation.svc/GetAccounts');
    }
  }
});
```

This returns the promise and you can handle it anywhere you call the acccount function or you could create a promise inside the function and return it. then inside the success or error methods resolve or reject it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to return your promise from the factory. Look at the following post under "Promises and Services"

http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/